# MVN running my functional test cases, error

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm getting this error on one particular environment but, no another PC:

```
    com.xxxx.site.functional.RegistrationFunctionalTest.testRegistrationLoginPopUpAvailable(com.xxxx.site.functional.RegistrationFunctionalTest)
   Run 1: RegistrationFunctionalTest.testRegistrationLoginPopUpAvailable:19->Locomotive.setText:277->Locomotive.setText:281->Locomotive.waitForElement:246 » NullPointer
   Run 2: RegistrationFunctionalTest>Locomotive.teardown:238 » NullPointer



 Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18:verify (default) @ xxxx-frontend ---
 [INFO] Failsafe report directory: C:\Users\IEUser\git\xxx_web\target\failsafe-reports
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 2:29.935s
 [INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 21 20:34:25 COT 2015
 [INFO] Final Memory: 73M/185M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18:verify (default) on project xxxxx-frontend: There are test failures.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\IEUser\git\xxxxx\target\failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
 ERROR: IllegalAccessException for stop method in class  org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.ExtendedTomcat
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at   org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.run.EmbeddedRegistry.shutdownAll(EmbeddedRegistry.java:110)
at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.run.EmbeddedRegistry$1.run(EmbeddedRegistry.java:69)
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardServer[-1]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:236)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:351)
... 6 more
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component   [StandardService[Tomcat]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:236)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:753)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
... 7 more
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:236)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
... 9 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/core/ContainerBase$StopChild
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
... 13 more
```

Basically what's happening is that this is running a functional test case using embedded Apache. The code is basically distributed across the team. For some folks it works but, for one particular developer, he's not able to run the mvn functional test cases.

Comment: Could you try to update the dependencies and try again? maybe with `mvn -U` or just to make sure, remove the repository folder in `.m2` folder

Comment: You didn't show relevant code nor stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing such problems various times. You have to be careful about global state within your test suite. If it works for some developers and for some not, it means that test ordering matters and thus some test is polluting global state and affecting other tests.

Try to reproduce test ordering that causes a failure (e.g. try to get logs of failed test suite and order test explicitly that way), simulate it on your machine and narrow down tests that are affecting each other. That way you can find what kind of nasty global state is it and fix it.

Other way is to hunt for global state (e.g. static variables, non-injected variables in singleton spring beans, ...) within area the test suite is failing and simply remove global state as it is bad practice.